# System.getProperty() showing null

Tags: java, system-properties

How so I get the default value of system property in java like ntlm.debug or jdk.tls.stapling. ignoreExtensions
On using system.getProperty(Property name) gives null. I am running with jdk version 11.0.7
Is there any other way to get default values of the properties?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also how are you running your program? From the command line or in an IDE (like Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ etc)

Comment: `import java.util.Properties;` 
`public class ListSystemProperties {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("jdk.tls.stapling.ignoreExtensions"));
  
 }

}
` This is basic code I am using and running from command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.getProperties() will give a map of all default properties of the system.
like
sun.management.compiler : HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.jnu.encoding : UTF-8
java.runtime.version : 14+36-1461
...
```

Comment: Thanks, so the ones not listed by this are not default and need to be specified explicitly?

Comment: Yes,  System.getProperties().put("hello", "hello");